# Creating PDF on FTP server in C#

Tags: c#, .net, ftp, stream, itext

I'm trying to create a PDF on my host server.

I understand that I must use FTP authentication, however I'm not sure how to achieve writing the iTextSharp and `FileStream`.

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(Server.MapPath("Quotation/quote.pdf"), 
    FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None);
string imagepath = "images/logo/logo4.png";
Document doc = new Document();
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, fs);
doc.Open();
```

So I need to authenticate that creation to the FTP server.

Comment: please tell which line is throwing the exception and what is exception message.

Comment: The above code is supposed to create a PDF File on my web hosts server. Therefore it requires FTP Authentication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `FileStream` with FTP.

Use `FtpWebRequest` and its [`FtpWebRequest.GetRequestStream`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.ftpwebrequest.getrequeststream) to upload an in-memory generated content to FTP server:

```
FtpWebRequest request =
    (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://ftp.example.com/remote/path/file.pdf");
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;  

using (Stream ftpStream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    Document doc = new Document();
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, ftpStream);
    doc.Open();
    // ...
}
```